# Can you set up a OneDrive folder to drop a copy of a file into multiple shared folders?

Tags: onedrive

This is a very specific situation I'm asking about, so I'm not interested in alternate solutions, I want to know if this can be done.

In OneDrive, instead of dragging files into multiple shared folders, is there a way to set up a single folder that will automatically send a copy to all the rest?

I need to share a folder full of PDF files to a number of people every two weeks, and they all have different folders on their one drive they want the package delivered to. So instead of uploading the folder to each persons OneDrive one at a time, I'd like to set up a drop folder so I can drop the package folder into it and it will automatically upload to everyones respective folders.

I can use Windows or Mac, web or desktop client, so whatever works will be what I use exclusively going forward.

Comment: Are you using the desktop client or the web client?

Comment: Also, which OS is this for, and is it specific to files or can it be all files in a certain folder gets shared between several shared folders?

Comment: Also, can you write an example of what you want to see to make it more clear?

Comment: Going to agree with @LPChip, it's hard to understand what you want, I can parse it two different ways.

Comment: @LPChip, I've updated my question.

Comment: There are synchronization programs.  You setup the job once then just let the task run every 2 weeks.  I suggest something like that.

Comment: Why not just create one folder for this and share it with them so they sync directly with this specific folder? (say, the way it was meant to be done?)

Comment: But the other way around would be to use mklink to create directory junctions. Whatever you place in the source folder, will automatically be placed in wherever the links are. Impractical, but it would be the solution to your question.

Comment: @LPChip Because reasons... Mostly because I'm dealing with old people, ultimately because this is the way my boss decided this is the way it's going to be done, even though the other way makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the web interface, you cannot do this. However, if you are using the desktop interface, you can make a batch file to do this for you:

```
xcopy /d DropFolder\* FolderA\
xcopy /d DropFolder\* FolderB\
```

Note the `/d`: this will overwrite only if the file in your drop folder is newer than the existing file in Folder A or B.

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

I assume you have access to a shared onedrive of the other members, and your goal is to populate all these shared folders simultaneously by just populating one folder, this would be the way to go.

In once place, you create a folder which will serve as the host. The documents in this folder will be spread to the rest. Whether this folder is in your own one drive, somewhere on your harddrive, or in one of the shared folders doesn't matter.

For the sake of making things clear, I'll refer to this as Host.

For example: `C:\users\Host\OneDrive`

I'll assume we're having 3 guests, namely Guest1, Guest2 and Guest3 of which each of these gets a subfolder within your Onedrive, namely: `C:\users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1` etc.

Now, lets assume you have placed the documents in question in the following folder: `C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host\PDF` and you want this folder to automatically be pushed/updated to the Guest1, Guest2 and Guest3's subfolder called PDF (eg: `C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1\PDF`) the following technique will allow you to do that.

MKLink is a tool that will create virtual directories that point to another directory. OneDrive will not see this as a virtual directory and for that reason backup the content. It is imperitive that you do not link directly to a parent folder, because that would create a loop, and will fill your OneDrive until it ran out of space, or the folder level is too deep.

## How to create this virtual directory

Open a command prompt as administrator.

1. Press start, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>OK</kbd> on the UAC dialog to allow Administrative access to the command prompt.

Use `cd` to navigate to the OneDrive folder by typing `cd "\Users\Host\OneDrive"`

```
C:\Windows\System32>cd "\Users\Host\OneDrive"

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive>_
```

*I'm going to assume here that you haven't yet made the folders and files. Otherwise, adjust where you see fit.*

Use `md` to create a new folder called Host by typing `md Host`

```
C:\Users\Host\OneDrive>md Host

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive>_
```

Navigate to this folder by typing `cd Host`

```
C:\Users\Host\OneDrive>cd Host

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host>_
```

Create a folder called PDF by typing `md PDF` and navigate to it by typing `cd PDF`

```
C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host>md PDF

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host>cd PDF

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host\PDF>_
```

Now that the host part is ready, lets create the links for the guests.

Navigate to the first guest's folder by typing: `cd \Users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1`

```
C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host\PDF>cd \Users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1>_
```

Now comes the magic, we create the virtual folder.

Type `mklink /j PDF C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host\PDF`

```
C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1>mklink /j PDF C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host\PDF
Junction created for PDF <<===>> C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Host\PDF

C:\Users\Host\OneDrive\Guest1>_
```

Do the same for Guest2 and Guest3 and whenever you place a file in one of these PDF folders, it automatically syncs between all clients. This includes that if one of the guests places a file in the PDF folder, it syncs too, as well as removing a file.